# How to pass the value of a char array to a function in another file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm currently in the process of rewriting the interpreter I've been working on in C. I'm used to higher level languages like C# so C is a bit confusing for me at this time.

I've wrote a function that detects the current operating system and stores either "WINDOWS", "LINUX" or "MAC" in a char array but I need to pass that value to a function in another file. The code is as follows:

```
//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "interpreter.h"

#define OS_STR_MAX 8

extern void interpreterInit(char currentOS[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    char currentOperatingSystem[OS_STR_MAX];
    ...
    interpreterInit(currentOperatingSystem);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I pass the value to the function all that gets stored is ANSII characters. I've searched for hours and can't find a solution.

```
//interpreter.h
#include <stdio.h>

void interpreterInit(char currentOS[]){
    ...
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot pass arrays to functions or assign them. You can only pass pointers that point into arrays. This is a bit like pass by reference in C#. Unfortunately this is not a topic that can be succintly explained in one SO answer. You need to find learning material elsewhere.

Comment: What does *"all that gets stored is ANSII characters"* mean?  What is the definition of `interpreterInit`?

Comment: What did you expect other than ANSII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate a char array in the memory and share it's pointer with whatever you want. This will work only while the program is running.

For example, in main.c you can write:

```
char * ptr = malloc( array_size * sizeof(char) );
```

You will have to `#include <stdlib.h>` for this function. This will allocate an array of `array_size` characters in  the memory . `ptr` will point to it's beginning.

You can any string you want using `strdup` function:

```
ptr = strdup( currentOperatingSystem );
```

You'll have to `#include <string.h>` for this function. Then you can pass the pointer we created to any function you want. For example:

```
interpreterInit( ptr );
```

This function will receive the pointer `ptr` which points to the string we want. For more information about dynamically allocated memory and strings to pointers, you can check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-for-strings-in-c/)